# Is it possible to make different mouseClicked() for the same class?

Tags: java, components, awt, mouselistener

My java program already have a Canvas, I plan to add 4 Components with MouseListener to that Canvas to act as 4 Buttons. Of course 4 "buttons" will respond differently

Can i create only ONE class for that 4 components (I dont know how to do this), or I have to define 4 classes for 4 components (this is easier)?

Answer (score 0):

[`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) extends `EventObject` which has the method [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29).

As an aside, it is better to add an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to buttons, since it will react not only to the mouse, but also to the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for comment Andrew, i will try what you said. By the way, I have a Container and I define a new class that derived from Component, I created an object from that new class, and add it to the Component said before. I think that to display the new component i have to use the paint() method of that new component. But finally, nothing display. What can i do with this, my code is rather long and hard to track, but if you need, i will give it to all of you here.     Thanks again!

Comment: *"my code is rather long"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ciCanvas extends Container
{
    public void paint()
    {
    // I draw an image here, it works perfectly



      Image MainMenuPlayBtImage = 
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ciConfig.CI_BT1_PATH) ;                
      Label MainMenuPlayText = new Label(ciConfig.CI_TEXT_PLAYBT) ;

      Point MainMenuPlayLocation = new Point(100, 100) ;

      ciTitle MainMenuBt = new ciTitle(MainMenuPlayText, MainMenuPlayBtImage, MainMenuPlayLocation) ;

      this.add(MainMenuBt) ;
    }

}
```

ciTitle extends Component and the following 4 lines of code aims to add a Component to this Container

**I hope this will display that ciTitle Component but nothing appear, note that i had also implemented codes for ciTitle.paint() method (see below)**

```
public void paint(Graphics _GraphicsDev)
{
    setSize(
            this.ciTitleImage.getWidth(this),
            this.ciTitleImage.getHeight(this));

    _GraphicsDev.drawImage(
            this.ciTitleImage, 
            this.ciTitleLocation.x, 
            this.ciTitleLocation.y, 
            this) ;


}
```

There are still some codes that have no definition here but i hope those are enough to describe the problem